# Disabling itemrenderer Hovered state

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, mxml

My itemrenderer has 2 custom states, no hovered state, and no normal state

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="state1" />
    <s:State name="state2" />
</s:states>
```

When I initialize it, I force it to go to `state2`. The problem is that when the mouse `rolls out` away from the item, it relapses back to the first state `state1`. It's kind of weird since I don't really have a hovered/unhover state. Anyone knows how to prevent this from happening? maybe by somehow disabling the `rollout` effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look into doing something with the mouse events, such as MouseOver

http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:mouseOver

However, I'm pretty sure that when you use something as an itemRenderer, the list class can exert some control over the itemRenderer.  It is entirely possible the List class is causing the behaviour you see.  What class are you using?  What is your renderer?

Comment: It's an itemrenderer in a list. After careful observation, it seems it resets when it's rolled out from. Is there a way I can reset the built-in rollout effect to not do anything.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "reset" .  You probably want to look at the styles selectionColor and rollOverColor.  
http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/spark/components/List.html#styleSummary

Answer (score 2):

***UPDATE***

that solved it for me: i am setting and reading the current state from a dataprovider.
and "normal" and "hovered" are always based on the current state so nothing changes when you hover over itemrenderer.

```
<s:states>
  <s:State name="normal" basedOn="{data.@state}"/>
  <s:State name="hovered" basedOn="{data.@state}"/>
  <s:State name="state1"/>
  <s:State name="state2"/>
</s:states>
```

---

"I'm not sure what you mean by "reset"."

i have the same problem here.
he wants to keep the state when a rollout occurs. this has nothing to do with the styles. its just about the states.

i have found this but i am not able to use it in my build up.
http://ianserlin.com/index.php/2009/12/15/disabling-rollout-behavior-of-a-selected-item-in-a-flex-4-list/

Answer (score 1):

You can find the solution by digging into the ItemRenderer source.  Searching for "rollout" finds this:

```
private function addHandlers():void
{
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, itemRenderer_rollOverHandler);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, itemRenderer_rollOutHandler);
}
```

Looking at the "itemRenderer_rollOutHandler" method, it contains:

```
protected function itemRenderer_rollOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    hovered = false;
}
```

Checking out the "hovered" member, you can see that it has a setter function:

```
protected function set hovered(value:Boolean):void
{
    if (value != _hovered)
    {
        _hovered = value;
        setCurrentState(getCurrentRendererState(), playTransitions);
        if (autoDrawBackground)
        {
            redrawRequested = true;
            super.$invalidateDisplayList();
        }
    }
}
```

Part of this sets the current state.  The good thing is that it's a protected method which means we can override it.  So if you never use the hover state in your ItemRenderer, it is sufficient to add this to the script block:

```
override protected function set hovered(value:Boolean):void
{
    // do nothing
}
```

The hovered state and background drawing will not happen as a result, so the rollout event listener will have no effect and your states won't be impacted.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is:

```
override protected function getCurrentRendererState():String
{
    return currentState;
}
```

This way when rolled out or deselected your item renderer won't try to switch to it's 'normal' state.
I used it in conjunction with Validators to set an error state of the renderer. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the following link:

> i have found this but i am not able to use it in my build up.
>   http://ianserlin.com/index.php/2009/12/15/disabling-rollout-behavior-of-a-selected-item-in-a-flex-4-list/

I had a similar issue; based on the data i had two types of normal states and after mouse-out, i wanted the renderer to identify which of the two states to revert to. I used the "override function" solution given in the above link to achieve the desired effect.

My Solution:

```
            override protected function itemRenderer_rollOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
                if (data.index == 0) {
                    this.currentState = "keyNormal";
                }
                else {
                    this.currentState = "normal";
                }
            }
```

I just entered the above code in the  block in my custom ItemRenderer.

Answer (score 0):

ItemRenderers actually delegate their normal, hover & selected states to an internal class called InteractiveStateDetector, not to a parent list.  This can be verified by simply using an ItemRenderer in a simple UI and manually attaching its data (make and itemRenderer with a label bound to the currentState value is the easiest way to see this).  You will see that it still changes state based on the current UX.

With that in mind, Adobe has brilliantly left out any means of disabling this without getting messy.  However you can do as Dennis suggests and override the getCurrentRendererState function for most use cases.

My particular use case was that I wanted to leverage my itemRenderer in a non-renderer setup with only minor state changes, but it didn't recognize that I declared its currentState to "nonRenderer".  It would default to "normal".